# Juntar o resultado de dois comandos Select's - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, select

Minha necessidade é unir o resultado de dois comandos select's para que me seja retornado tudo de uma vez, por exemplo nesse comando:

```
SELECT codigosuprimento, suprimento, count (codigosuprimento) quantidade, estoqueminimo, 
count (codigosuprimento) - estoqueminimo as saldo
    FROM public.estoque, public.suprimento where usado = '0' and codigosuprimento = 155 and
    public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo group by codigosuprimento, suprimento, estoqueminimo order by suprimento;
```

Eu trago a situação atual do suprimento de codigo `155` no estoque, Meu retorno é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nesse comando :

```
SELECT public.estoque.codigosuprimento,COUNT (public.estoque.codigosuprimento) as qtdSuprimento
FROM public.entrega, public.entregaitem, public.estoque
WHERE public.entrega.codigo = public.entregaitem.codigoentrega and codigosuprimento = 155 and
public.entregaitem.codigoestoque = public.estoque.codigo and public.entrega.data >= CURRENT_DATE - 30 
GROUP BY public.estoque.codigosuprimento  
ORDER BY codigosuprimento
```

Eu trago quantos suprimentos foram requisitados nos últimos trinta dias, e meu retorno é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha necessidade seria unir os resultados para que tivesse algo semelhante a isso:

```
codigosuprimento | suprimento | quantidade | estoqueminimo | saldo | qtdSolicitada
        155      |  50F0Z00   |     54     |        10     |   44  |       19
```

Fiz um teste e coloquei uma `query` assim:

```
SELECT codigosuprimento, suprimento, count (codigosuprimento) quantidade, estoqueminimo, 
count (codigosuprimento) - estoqueminimo as saldo, 
(SELECT COUNT (public.estoque.codigosuprimento) as qtdSuprimento
FROM public.entrega, public.entregaitem, public.estoque
WHERE public.entrega.codigo = public.entregaitem.codigoentrega and codigosuprimento = 155 and
public.entregaitem.codigoestoque = public.estoque.codigo and public.entrega.data >= CURRENT_DATE - 30) as trinta
FROM public.estoque, public.suprimento where usado = '0' and codigosuprimento = 155 and
public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo group by codigosuprimento, suprimento, estoqueminimo order by suprimento;
```

E desse modo ela me trouxe o resultado esperado, porém quando fui testar para trazer sem a condição de trazer apenas para o suprimento de código `155` ela já me trouxe resultados sem sentido. Tentei desse modo a `query` e me trouxe os resultados errados:

```
SELECT codigosuprimento, suprimento, count (codigosuprimento) quantidade, estoqueminimo, 
count (codigosuprimento) - estoqueminimo as saldo, 
(SELECT COUNT (public.estoque.codigosuprimento) as qtdSuprimento
FROM public.entrega, public.entregaitem, public.estoque
WHERE public.entrega.codigo = public.entregaitem.codigoentrega and
public.entregaitem.codigoestoque = public.estoque.codigo and public.entrega.data >= CURRENT_DATE - 30) as trinta
FROM public.estoque, public.suprimento where usado = '0' and
public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo group by codigosuprimento, suprimento, estoqueminimo order by suprimento;
```

Comment: Já tentou dar um `(select1...) UNION (select2...)`?

Comment: @Zulian já, porém para usar o `UNION` é necessário que ambos os retornos possuam o mesmo numero de colunas

Comment: Mesmo colocando as colunas "adicionais" como `null`?

Comment: O problema é que ele trouxe o conteúdo do segundo select na segunda linha sendo que eu preciso que seja na mesma

Comment: Um subselect fica mas custoso para o db mas acho que te atenderia

Comment: Assim como eu coloquei na minha pergunta @CaiqueRomero?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero tu teria algum exemplo de como fazer com subselects?

Comment: Ao inves de você preencher 155  você coluna a coluna codigo do primeiro select

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, como assim?

Comment: Demonstrei na resposta, veja se consegui te ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT codigosuprimento
  , suprimento
  , count (codigosuprimento) quantidade
  , estoqueminimo
  , count (codigosuprimento) - estoqueminimo AS saldo
  , (
     SELECT COUNT (estoque2.codigosuprimento) as qtdSuprimento
     FROM public.entrega
        , public.entregaitem
        , public.estoque AS estoque2 --Renomeio a tabela para relacionar ambas as querys
     WHERE public.entrega.codigo = public.entregaitem.codigoentrega 
        AND public.estoque.codigosuprimento = estoque2.codigosuprimento-- Relaciono as 2 querys
        AND public.entregaitem.codigoestoque = estoque2.codigo 
        AND public.entrega.data >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
    ) AS trinta
FROM public.estoque
   , public.suprimento 
WHERE usado = '0' 
   AND codigosuprimento = 155 
   AND public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo 
GROUP BY codigosuprimento
  , suprimento
  , estoqueminimo
ORDER BY suprimento;
```

Comment: Perfeito funcionou como precisava, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Fico feliz que deu certo :)